# Docker run - how to share UTS namespace between containers?

Tags: docker, linux-namespaces

Docker run command by default uses a dedicated UTS namespace for the container and because of it the container gets its own/unique hostname. I am trying to share the UTS namespace between two containers but it seems that it is not possible with docker run command.

Following are the commands that I ran -

```
docker run -d --name container1 alpine sleep infinity
docker run -it --name container2 --uts container:container1 alpine /bin/sh
```

Error -

```
docker: --uts: invalid UTS mode.
```

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#uts-settings---uts), it looks like it is not possible to reference a container with the --uts flag. This is not the case with other namespace related flags like --pid, --network, etc. They support referencing other containers. Why "container:<name|id>” mode is not supported by the --utc flag? How to share UTS namespace between containers so that they share hostname?

Comment: I read the documentation of Docker and it seems impossible to specify anything else than "host". With LXC containers, it is possible to make it: the lxc-start accepts the option "--share-uts=..."

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to share UTS namespace between containers. But, if your final aim is just to share `hostname` between containers, next should work if you not care about network share:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker run -idt --name container1 ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
3b024de861049c63852e5b196b8730c23ccba8454eb894aa1159c046dd35043e
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker run -idt --name container2 --net container:container1 ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
ee3d696a589bb7aa3000cec7587f4b920088edf829f8cda029b019316451e92f
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec -it container1 hostname
3b024de86104
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec -it container2 hostname
3b024de86104
```

It let `container2` use the same network of `container1`, refers to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings). FYI in case this help.

Another way maybe just expose `/etc/hostname` to `bind mounts` or `volume`, and let all containers which you needed to use the same one, then you no need to share net.